# Android Studio: Package name not set to a valid package name

Tags: android, package-name

[image]

I want to create an activity in the "layout" package so I right-clicked it and selected new activity and it's giving me this error. How do I resolve it?

Comment: Please read this carefully https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 5):

> I want to create an activity in the "layout" package

First, I strongly recommend getting some fundamental knowledge about Android.

As for your question - `layout` is NOT a package name. Packages are visible under `java` node in your project structure view (in `Android` mode). What you see  in `res` node are resources (images, XMLs etc). It's not a place to put your code, yet you can create package "layout" by hand if you really need, however you'd be violating package name conventions: See docs on the subject http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: well elaborate .

Answer (score 0):

Package is not layout. You can get your package name in the manifest file. example: manifest package="com.example.helloworld.android"

Answer (score 0):

go to AndroidManifest.xml in your project, copy package name(3rd line) from there and past it here in the last field.